# Global variable I can add to in liquid

Tags: liquid, shopify-liquid

I currently have the following variable in a page with liquid:

```
{% assign tagQty = 0 %}
```

I would like to loop through some cart items and add to this variable.  I need to track each additional quantity and the variable needs to contain the total.  This is my attempt:

```
{% for item in cart.items %}
  {% for tag in item.product.tags %}
    {% if tag == 'Speicific-Tag' %}
      {% tagQty = tagQty | plus: item.quantity %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The above gives an error as this is invalid: `{% tagQty = tagQty | plus: item.quantity %}`
I have also tried: `{{ tagQty = tagQty | plus: item.quantity }}` which is also invalid.

I can reassign tagQty but that defeats the purpose as I need to collect the total of this specific product tag to display it.  Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out I had to reassign the variable.

```
{% assign tagQty = tagQty | plus: item.quantity %}
```